srand no funciona (c)
persona media nueva en la área de programación pero no se si es problema del compilador o de algo mayor pero cuando intento usar la función de srand en un código que tiene que generar números aleatorios en c hasta sacar uno en concreto "en el ejemplo que daré será 4" simplemente se termina el código sin generar nada o automáticamente acaba
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(){
  int rng;
  while(rng!=4){
    srand(time(NULL));
    rng = rand() % 21 ;
    printf("%d",rng);
  }
}

me sale esto cada ves que intento compilar y ejecutar que se que sale a acabar con un codigo

alguna ayuda o sugerencia

¿ Te sale eso cada vez que le das a compilar o a ejecutar ? Son dos cosas MUY DISTINTAS.

Un problema es que en el while, en el primer ciclo, estás haciendo una comparación con una variale no inicializada. Esto puede dar comportamientos impredecibles en la ejecución (y si es que te deja compilar). Puedes declarar un valor inicial, por ejemplo: int rng=-1;

Probablemente quieres inicializar la semilla antes de entrar al bucle en vez de cambiarla en cada iteración.

Tu código me funciona en VS2022 (después de configurar "int rng=0;" para poder compilarlo sin error)

Los comentarios ya incluyen los claves para corregir el programa. Incluyo un código alternativo como referencia y una explicación más detallada de los problemas.
int main () {
  int rng;
  srand (time (NULL));
  while ((rng = rand() %21) != 4)  printf ("%d ", rng);
  fflush (stdout);
}

En este ejemplo, como se indica en los comentarios, la variable rng se inicializa antes de ser usada, pero en este caso ya con el primer valor útil. Una alternativa a este código sería utilizar un bucle do ... while.
Por otra parte, rand utiliza un generador lineal congruencial de números pseudoaleatorios. Estos generadores utilizan un cierto estado para generar el siguiente valor. La función srand simplemente inicializa ese estado, así que solo es necesario ejecutarla una vez por programa. En general, si conoces el estado del generador (el valor que pasas a srand) puedes volver a generar la misma secuencia de valores aleatorios. Por eso se llaman números pseudoaleatorios.
El otro punto que puede haberte causado problemas es que la salida de consola no es inmediata. Los valores se almacenan en un buffer y solo se envían a la consola bajo determinadas condiciones (recibir un caracter EndOfLine ,esto es \n generalmente, o un EndOfFile esto se genera pulsando CTRL+D).
Puedes forzar el flushing (mostrar lo que hayas escrito hasta el momento o vaciar-flush- el buffer) de la salida estándard usando fflush(stdout) o simplemente imprimiendo un caracter EOL (printf ("\n");). Si no haces esto, en el mejor de los casos la salida de tu programa no se generará  en el orden correcto.
